# How to read only English characters

Tags: ruby, regex

I am reading a file that sometimes has Chinese and characters of languages other than English.

How can I write a regex that only reads English words/letters?

Should it just be `/^[a-zA-Z]+/`?

If I do the above, then words like "eété" will still be picked but I don't want that:

```
"été".match(/^[a-zA-Z]+/) => #nil  good I didn't want that word

"eété".match(/^[a-zA-Z]+/) => #not nil  tricked into picking something I did not want
```

Comment: Contrary to popular opinion, not all English words will fit within ASCII unmolested. This is usually the case for words of French origin (e.g. naïve).

Comment: true. yes it is french. but if I can have my above regex apply to each and every character in the word then it might work..

Comment: How do you propose rejecting words like `eété` while still capturing words like `café`?

Comment: Not all languages other than English have characters outside of `[a-zA-Z]`. Because the Unicode consortium rejected Klingon script, Klingon language is represented in the Latin alphabet unless you use the Private User Area of Unicode. But you won't have to deal with that in your first iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `$`, which means end of line:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+$/
```

Or if you use such filtration:

```
strings.select { |s| /^[a-zA-Z]+$/ =~ s }
# which is equal to strings.grep /^[a-zA-Z]+$/
```

you can use negative filtration method with slightly simplier regex:

```
strings.reject { |s| /[^a-zA-Z]/ =~ s }
```

where `[^a-zA-Z]` means *any non-english character*.

Comment: `[^a-zA-Z]` certainly **does not mean** *any non-English character*! It means one character that is not in the listed ranges.  You must describe it as I have, not as you have, or you will incur many false negatives and many false positives.  Your description is invalid, even though the code may have some sort of desired effect (although I rather doubt that).  If you just want nothing but 6-bit Radix-50 characters, fine, but aren’t we about to start the second decade of the third millennium?  Seems like this sort of provincialism doesn’t help anybody.

Answer (score 4):

The only truly English letter that comes to mind is *wynn* **ƿ**.

One could make an argument for *eth* **ð** and *thorn* **þ**, but it would be a much weaker argument than can be made for *wynn*.

Other than those, English typically uses the Latin alphabet, albeit with certain modifications. *Wynn* possibly excepted, there is no such thing as an English letter, only a Latin letter.

There certainly exist regular expressions that demand that base characters be in the Latin or Common scripts, such as for example

```
(?:[\p{Script=Latin}\p{Script=Common}]\pM*+)+
```

but as you haven’t specified whether you’re using a 7- or 8-bit version of Ruby or a 21-bit version,  I’m not sure what to tell you.

Comment: Is the term "Latin" misleading, because Ancient Romans didn't use "j"?

Comment: @Andrew: The archaic Latin alphabet didn’t even have a G or a Z. That’s all water under the bridge now. My real point relates to how you can talk about characters that have the Unicode property `\p{Script=Latin}`, but that you cannot do so for `\p{Script=English}`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's useful to use the Iconv library to deal with non-ASCII:

```
require 'iconv'

utf8_to_latin1 = Iconv.new("LATIN1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", "UTF8") # !> encoding option isn't portable: TRANSLIT//IGNORE
utf8_to_ascii_translit = Iconv.new("ASCII//TRANSLIT", "UTF8") # !> encoding option isn't portable: TRANSLIT
utf8_to_ascii_ignore = Iconv.new("ASCII//IGNORE", "UTF8") # !> encoding option isn't portable: IGNORE

resume = "Résumé"
utf8_to_latin1.iconv(resume) # => "R\xE9sum\xE9"
utf8_to_ascii_translit.iconv(resume) # => "R'esum'e"
utf8_to_ascii_ignore.iconv(resume) # => "Rsum"
```

Notice that Ruby is warning that the option choices are not portable. That means there might be some damage to the string being processed; The "//TRANSLIT" and "//IGNORE" options can degrade the string but for our purpose it's OK.

James Gray wrote a nice article about [Encoding Conversion With iconv](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/encoding_conversion_with_iconv), which is useful for understanding what Iconv can do, along with dealing with UTF-8 and Unicode characters.