# In Ruby, how to automatically convert non-supported characters in text-processing?

Tags: ruby, text

(Using Ruby 1.8)

I only have a brief understanding of encoding and such...but what I want to know is, in any given script handling any given text-file, is there some universal library or call I need to make to turn non-standard characters into their nearest printable equivalent. I realize there's no "all-in-one" fix, but this is for a English (U.S. gov't) text file, and so I'm wondering if there's something that mitigates what must be a relatively common issue in English text formatting.

For example, in a text file, I have an entry like this:

```
0-8­23
```

That hyphen is just literally a hyphen as I've typed it out. In the file though, it's something that looks like a hyphen (an n-dash?) but when copy and pasting it...for example, into this browser text box, it doesn't show up.

Printing it out via a Ruby script gets this:

```
08�23
```

How do I get my script to resolve it into a dash. Or something other than a gremlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very common to run into [hyphen-like characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen#Unicode) and [dashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash), especially in the output of word-processors. Converting them isn't too hard if you know what the byte is that represents the character, but gets to be a pain when you get a document with several different ones. It gets worse as you throw other accented characters into the mix.

Ruby 1.8 doesn't support multibyte and Unicode character sets as well as 1.9+, but you can work around that somewhat by using the [Iconv](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/iconv/1.8.7/frames) library.

Iconv lets you convert between various character-sets, such as US-ASCII, ISO-8859-1 and WIN-1252. It's smarter than a regex, because it knows how to convert from accented characters, to similarly looking characters, or ignore them if nothing similar exists, allowing your transliteration to degrade gracefully.

I have [some example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563079/how-to-read-only-english-characters/4580155#4580155) in an answer to a related question. Also read James Grey's article linked in the answer. It explains the problem and ways to fix it, ending up with recommending Iconv too.

Answer (score 0):

You could whitelist with gsub:

```
string.gsub(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/)
```

Without knowing more information, I can't build the perfect regex for you, but the general idea is to replace anything that's not what you're expecting (anything not a letter or number or expected symbols).

Comment: Ah ok, I was just checking if there was a way to typecast into ASCII. So any service that tries to normalize accented characters, such as è to e, they have a long regex to handle it?

Comment: umm, not necessarily. They could have multiple regexs or they could use natural language processing to  do so. For example, it would read a sentence (in Spanish) ¿Dondé? and know that Dond(+) with a single question mark has a 89% of being dondé and process accordingly