# Only allow English characters in a string in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I've been using this:

```
if value.chars.count < value.bytes.count
  puts "Some non english characters found."
end
```

But this incorrectly marks the following as non-English.

`React and You: A Designer’s Point of View`

How can I easily check if a string has no Asian/French/Russian characters?

I can probably iterate through each char in the string and if `.bytes == 1` add it to a temp var. Then if that temp var is not nil it means it's an English character. But this seems rather convoluted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to read only english characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563079/how-to-read-only-english-characters)

Comment: See "[mcve]". We need input data and expected output.

Comment: @theTinMan re-read the question there's an example string that's being marked as non-english because of the dash and the apostrophe.

Comment: @Gerry the solutions in that answer works for single words, but not sentences.

Comment: Is é as in "resumé" or "fiancée" an Engish letter? What about ö as in "coördinate"? What about “ and ” or ’? Or ? English is a really unruly language since it steals and borrows from so many others. It's also quite common to try and represent personal names using their native Latin representation even if that involves accents, as Polish names like "Michał Życzkowski" are usually put in as-is.

Comment: There is no dash in the sample. The apostrophe was not obvious due to the HTML formatting you chose.

Comment: What does the size in bytes have to do with the language characters? The size in bytes has to do with the encoding, not the language. E.g. in UTF-32, all characters are encoded in 4 bytes, in UTF-16, all characters are encoded in 2 or 4 bytes, in UTF-8, all characters are encoded in 1-4 bytes, in ISO8859-15, characters are encoded in 1 byte, but ISO8859-15 can only represent a tiny subset of all characters.

Comment: Also, what does "English character" even mean? Emily Brontë's *Wuthering Heights* is considered a masterpiece of English literature … I guess in your world, its author wasn't English?

Answer (score 1):

**As pointed out in the comments ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467367/only-allow-english-characters-in-a-string-in-rails/44467530#comment75932452_44467367) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467367/only-allow-english-characters-in-a-string-in-rails/44467530#comment75932505_44467530)), this solution will reject some english words with letters that *may* be considered as "non English" characters.**

---

Using the answer provided in "[How to read only English characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563079/how-to-read-only-english-characters)" you could adjust it to remove any punctuation character or space, and make the comparison wit that same regex, something like this:

```
str = "React and You: A Designer’s Point of View"
str.gsub(/[[:punct:]]|\s/, "") =~ /^[a-zA-Z]+$/
#=> 0
```

`.gsub(/[[:punct:]]|\s/, "")` will remove any punctuation character or space, so you can compare that with the `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/` regexp.

Here are step by step examples:

```
str = "React and You: A Designer’s Point of View"
str.gsub!(/[[:punct:]]|\s/, "")         #=> "ReactandYouADesignersPointofView"
str =~ /^[a-zA-Z]+$/                    #=> 0

str = "Comment ça va?"
str.gsub!(/[[:punct:]]|\s/, "")         #=> "Commentçava"
str =~ /^[a-zA-Z]+$/                    #=> nil
```

If you are expecting numbers too, then change the regexp to: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/`.

As pointed out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467367/only-allow-english-characters-in-a-string-in-rails/44467530?noredirect=1#comment75949734_44467530), note that using `[[:punct:]]` will allow non-english punctuation characters such as `¿` or `¡`; so, if those characters are also expected (and must cause to reject the sentence as valid), then maybe it is better to avoid `gsub` and compare to a custom regex with all allowed characters, for example<sup>1</sup>:

```
str =~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9\[\]{}\\*:;@$%&#?!|’'"-\.\/_\s]+$/
```

<sup>1</sup> *This is just an example with most common characters that i could think of, but needs to be customized with any character considered as* valid.

Comment: The English expression ["déjà vu"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Déjà_vu) would get rejected by this.

Comment: Yes, just checked your comment, so many more could get rejected.

Comment: This sort of stuff is deceptively tricky. I'm not even sure there's a list of quasi-legitimate English characters. Good try though!

Comment: @tadman Thank you! Maybe a complete solution would involve some sort of "whitelisting" for those words containing special characters, but my guess it that it will need a long list of words (and some effort to gather them).

Comment: This assumes that other languages have the same punctuation as English. For example, if `str #=> "¿es lunes?"`, `str.gsub!(/[[:punct:]]|\s/, "") #=> "eslunes"; str =~ /^[a-zA-Z]+$/ #=> 0`, suggesting that the string has only English language characters.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Nice catch, if _foreign_ punctuation needs to be considered, then `[[:punct:]]` won't help; a custom regexp will be needed.